# Function warning for 'view' and code 'not reacheable'

Tags: solidity, remix

Refer the fn below :

```
function _check() internal returns(bool success) {
        for (uint i = 0; i<registered.length; i++ ) {
            if(registered[i] == msg.sender) {
                return true;
            } else {
            return false;
            }
        }
        
     }
```

Remix is showing two warnings :

1. Function state mutability can be restricted to view.
2. Unreacheable code `i++`.

How can I silent the two? Is the function truly 'view' ?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unreachable code it is not a warning it is a bug in your code? you are only checking the first element in the registered array and return directly false or true without looking at the rest of the array !!!! -__-

Yes it is view, View functions are functions which do not change the storage

```
function _check() internal view returns(bool success) {
    for (uint i = 0; i < registered.length - 1; i++) {
        if(registered[i] == msg.sender) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
 }
```